# Why data doesn't send to KAFKA topic using python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, apache-kafka

I don't know whats a problem.
I read data from the MYSQL database and want to send it to Kafka.
But script run without a problem and stay in the sending moment

```
def parse(d,param):  # распарс
    r={}
    if str(type(d)) == "<class 'dict'>":
        # print(d)
        return (d)
    return -1

s_con = pymysql.connect(host="xxx", user="xxx", password="xxx", port=3306,
                                db="xxx", cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.SSCursor)
s_cur = s_con.cursor()

s_cur.execute(s_sql) 
         
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=param["BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS"],
                                 value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),)
print(producer)
while True:
    r = [dict((s_cur.description[i][0], value) \
                      for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in s_cur.fetchmany(
                1000)] 

    for d in r:
       j = parse(d, param)
       print(j)
       print(param["TOPIC"])
       producer.send(param["TOPIC"], value=j)
       sleep(5)
```

The result is below

[image]

Comment: Does this print anything?  `print(param["TOPIC"])`

Comment: Have you considered just using Kafka Connect to ingest from MySQL to Kafka, e.g. as shown at http://rmoff.dev/ksny19-no-more-silos

Comment: @mike67 Yes. I deleted this row